# How to force specific test class to be executed in a separate jvm?

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

In order to avoid race condition and isolate usage of a shared resource, I want to run some specific tests in a forked jvm.

How should I do it with Junit 5 & Gradle?

Comment: https://github.com/johnrengelman/gradle-processes could help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in Gradle, but in maven we can do that by excluding class or packages from a profile like that :

```
<configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
```

With a simple search, I found that it is possible with gradle.
You can check that link : [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering)